# DB2 Command Line Processor times out

Tags: db2

Freshly installed DB2 10.1 on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine.

I'm getting `DB21015E` error when I execute commands like:

```
sudo ./DB2 update DBM CFG using SYSADM_GROUP db2iadm1
```

or even

```
sudo ./DB2 get DMB CFG
```

Tried increasing the `DB2BQTIME` parameter but I don't think it has to do anything with that.

The online help also suggests that `'db2bp'` must reside in the correct folder, with execution rights. It sits in `/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin` with `-r-xr-xr-x`.

What else could go wrong? Is there a log file that I can check?

**UPDATE**

Run strace and it's telling me that /tls/x86_64/libm.so.6 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

who is your db2 user? db2inst1?  then you should execute the command as db2inst1

```
sudo -s 
su - db2inst1
db2 update DBM cfg using SYSADM_GROUP db2iadm1
```

note, no capitals in DB2

Comment: Thanks @Paul Bastide, tried but no luck. Same error. Could it be a PATH issue?

Comment: it's definitely the path.

Comment: have you gone ahead and checked to see if your instance is setup right, you should check your .bashrc or .profile and see if the sqllib directory loads the preferences ... also once you are su - db2inst1 you should do an ls -al and see sqlllib you can go in there to execute commands

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to execute these command with root (sudo). Most of the time, root does not have any right on a instance or database in db2. As Paul has said, you should change the session to the instance user, I suppose that in your case is db2inst1.

If your problem persist, the best is to drop and recreate the instance. This will not drop your current database.

```
sudo su -
cd /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/instance
./db2idrop db2inst1
./db2icrt -u db2inst1 db2inst1
```

The users could change for your security schema (fenced user, instance user, DB2 path, etc.)

Comment: you shouldn't need to do that, if the db2instance exists. just need to edit the .profile inorder to load the path

Comment: What about if the instance directory got corrupted? For example, some files were deleted. The best is to ensure that the instance is right. 
L4zl0w is trying to update an instance parameter and he is getting a DB21015, and that is quite weird in a normal instance.